# Excel VBA Autofill Multiple Unqiue Columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have 420 columns, each with a unique formula that changes by row number, with about 1500 rows in total.

For reasons I can't understand, the row number references in each forumla doesn't always update correctly when I'm refreshing the data query (from sharepoint list). However this only happens far down the sheet.

I can write a VBA script to autofill each column from the top cell to fix this;

```
Range("A2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A1555")
Range("B2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B2:B1555")
```

But this means repeating until column PD, a lot of typing.

Is there a more dynamic way to do this? The number of columns should never change, however the total number of rows likely will.

Comment: `Range("A2").Resize( , 420).AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2").Resize(1554, 420)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this in one operation:

```
Range("A2").Resize( , 420).AutoFill _
       Destination:=Range("A2").Resize(1554, 420)
```